# Get md5 checksums of entries in zip using adm-zip

Tags: node.js, zip

I am trying to get MD5 checksums for all files in a ZIP file. I am currently using `adm-zip` for this because I read I can read zip contents into the memory without having to extract a file to the disk. But I am failing to read the data of entries in a ZIP file. My code goes as follows:

```
var zip = new AdmZip(path);
zip.getEntries()
    .map(entry => { console.log(entry.entryName, entry.data); });
```

The `entryName` can be read, so opening and reading the zip works. But `data` is always `undefined`. I read that `data` is not *really* the method to read the data of an entry, but I am not sure how to actually read it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To read the data of the entry, you must call the method `getData()` of the entry object, which returns a `Buffer`. Here is the updated code snippet which works on my end :

```
var zip = new AdmZip(path);
zip.getEntries().map(entry => {
  const md5Hash = crypto.createHash('md5').update(entry.getData()).digest('hex');
  console.log(md5Hash);
});
```

I used the basic [`crypto`](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html) module to produce the md5 hash (in hex format). Don't forget to add it to the list of your requires at the top of your file: `const crypto = require('crypto');`